# @JsonFormat is not parsing ZonedDateTime correctly

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, zoneddatetime

I am having this DTO:

```
public class TransactionRequestDTO {
    
   private ZonedDateTime authDate;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
     @JsonProperty("authDate")
     public void setAuthDate(String authDate) {
     this.authDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(authDate);
   }
}
```

I am making REST API call with this json:

```
{
  "instrumentDate": "2020-02-28T05:50:24.000+02:00"
}
```

But I am receiving the Date as
`"2020-02-28T05:50:24.000+0200"` in `setAuthDate()` (without ':').

Hence it is giving exception :

```
'java.time.format.DateTimeParseException' at ZonedDateTime.parse(authDate).
```

Answer (score 4):

The Date & time represented in the string `2020-02-28T05:50:24.000+02:00` is of `ISO-8601` format, so you can simply use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
 @JsonProperty("authDate")
 public void setAuthDate(String authDate) {
 this.authDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(authDate);
}
```

In case if you want to still format into [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), just use the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with correct pattern

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
 @JsonProperty("authDate")
 public void setAuthDate(String authDate) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    this.authDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(authDate,formatter);
 }
```

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` will fail to parse `2020-02-28T05:50:24.000+02:00` using the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Comment: Thanks for input, since he overriden the `setter` method i believe jackson will not use that format during deserialization @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is not correct. Change it to one of the following patterns:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

or

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTime = "2020-02-28T05:50:24.000+02:00";

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-28T05:50:24+02:00
2020-02-28T05:50:24+02:00
```

Also, since your date-time is with a timezone offset of `+02:00` hours, you should consider using `OffsetDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime`. Some databases e.g. PostgreSQL do not support `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` and `OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]`.